# Grand Totals in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am trying to create the following in Tableau (fake numbers):

Col 1 - Person A number of correct answers = 5 ,  total questions = 10, % correct = 50

Col 2 - Person B number of correct answers = 8,  total questions = 8, % correct = 100

...

Col n - Person n number of correct answers = 9, total questions = 10, % correct = 90

Grand total - total correct answers for everyone, total questions for everyone, % correct

I would like for the grand total column to read 5+8+9 = 22, 10 + 8 + 10 = 28, 22/28 = 78.5%.

However, the % correct column for the grand total only has choices of average, min, max, or sum. % correct is a calculated field based on the other two fields. I want the calculated field to keep working even in the grand total column to give me 78.5%. Does anyone know how to get the answer I want of 78.5%?

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate whatever field is giving you the total correct answers and make the duplicated field a table calculation for percent of total. The Grand Total will include this column.